# ACCESS Jet SQL INT() Function -> SQL Server Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ms-access, function

I am converting an Access Jet-SQL query into T-SQL and I came upon the Int() function.  Now, I would like to convert it into T-SQL, and this is what I have so far:

```
--Works for Positive
Select CONVERT(INT, 1.2)
--Answer = 1

--Not the same as Access
SELECT CONVERT(INT, -1.2)
--Answer = -1
```

Now, according to [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/int.php), I need it to return -2, not -1.  Does anyone have cleaner T-SQL code than:

```
DECLARE @test FLOAT
SET @test = -1.2

SELECT CASE WHEN @test < 0 THEN CONVERT(INT, @test) - 1 ELSE CONVERT(INT, @test) END
```

Can anyone come up with cleaner code than this (T-SQL only)?  No UDFs as this is an adhoc query.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT FLOOR(@test)

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah...

```
select convert(int, floor(@test))
```

Never mind...